# Reusing the web browser control

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, webbrowser-control

I have a pure Win32 application (no MFC, etc.) to which I want to add a web browser control in a window. I know the basics of COM and can create a COM object for the browser using

```
 hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WebBrowser,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC,
    IID_IWebBrowser2,
    (void**) &pWebBrowser);
```

However, apparently one needs to call SetClientSite, passing an IOleClientSite*. How do I obtain such an interface? [This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451946.aspx) implements its own browser class, which provides the interface by deriving from it and implementing it [(here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451938.aspx). I tried to go along that path, but in order to instantiate the browser class, I would have to register it (no?). This seems awfully complicated - I just want to use an existing COM object, not implement and register my own. What am I missing?

Assuming I do implement my own ClientSite class as part of my application, is it possible to not register it, and just instantiate it by calling `new ClientSite` (and then fetch the interface as using `QueryInterface`)? Will this work, or is it mandatory to call `CoCreateInstance`?

Comment: You don't obtain the interface, you implement it, or find some other ActiveX container with the interface implemented, like MFC or ATL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example on [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4379/Display-a-Web-Page-in-a-Plain-C-Win32-Application.htm) and another on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla) which contains the simplest implementation for hosting a web browser control implemented in pure C. You do have to implement your own `IOleClientSite`, but it is one of the easier classes to implement. Yes, it is mandatory to call `CoCreateInstance` or `OleCreate` to create the instance of the web browser control.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4379/Display-a-Web-Page-in-a-Plain-C-Win32-Application.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. As you say, the example is in C, but I rewrote it as C++ code and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Dabbler how did you rewrote it as C++ ? a load of people trying to use it in c++ (and me) failing since we are noobs :| could you please post an example ? I have been looking into this for a whole day and couldnt find any simple c++ example. The problem is most of the links are dead, as example http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/webform.html lucian wischik one. I have been trying to use c code into my c++ one(my first ever c++ app) but unsucesfully till now.

Comment: @Tomas Here is the original sample the CodeProject article is based upon: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32. It is in C++, and is considerably more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try WTL (header only library from MS). Install its project templates. Create a new WTL  project from template and select "web browser" control option (or whatever is the name). Now you can investigate generated sources or (my personal recommendation) move your stuff into this project

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do ...

... but I'd start by trying to use a simple ShellExecute(), if at all possible:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816

Comment: What you are writing seems to apply for starting the external browser; I believe the OP was about using IE as a dialog control.